# If media queries do not affect specificity, how come the style is being applied even when placed on top

Tags: css

With this style

```css
div {
  @media (min-width: 0px) {
     color: blue;
  }
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
hello
</div>
```

I expect the color to be red. However, it's actually blue and I have no explanation for this. Tested on Chrome. The color is red in other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the nested `@rule`  actually unwraps to

```css
@rule {
  & {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

This is explained in [this paragraph](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/#conditionals) of the specs, which even contains [an example](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/#example-6f271ab7) pointing out this case:

> ```css
> .foo {
>   display: grid;
>
>   @media (orientation: landscape) {
>     grid-auto-flow: column;
>   }
> }
> /* equivalent to
>   .foo {
>     display: grid;
>
>     @media (orientation: landscape) {
>       & {
>         grid-auto-flow: column;
>       }
>     }
>   }
> */
> ```

And if we do add the `&` selector to the `color: red` rule, we get the same specificity:

```css
div {
  @media (min-width: 0px) {
     color: blue;
  }
  & { color: red; }
}
```

```html
<div>
hello
</div>
```

And note that your code currently produces a red output in non Chromium browsers because they still don't support CSS nesting, so they just treat the `@media` rule here as an invalid rule and go on to parse the `div` one.
If you want to support all browsers, you have to manually unwrap these rules:

```css
@media (min-width: 0px) {
  div { color: blue; }
}
div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
hello<!-- will be red everywhere -->
</div>
```

Comment: both already had the same specificity without adding `&`. The trick is a reorder made by the browser that make nested rule always considered later

Answer (score 1):

I will use another example to illustrate your issue:

```css
div {
  & {
    color: blue;
  }
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  hello
</div>
```

We are mixing "nested rules" and "declarations" and [the Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/#mixing) defines such behavior by moving the "nested rules" at the end.

So the browser will change your code to this:

```css
div {
  color: red;
  & {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  hello
</div>
```

And then to this:

```css
div {
  color: red;
}

div {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  hello
</div>
```

So always start with the "declarations" then the "nested rules"